# Add video in front of image (background) using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a png and would like to add there video, so png is my case is something like a border.

I trying :

```
ffmpeg -i cat.mp4 -framerate 30 -i dem.png -filter_complex "[0]pad=1920:1080:500:0[vid];[vid][1]overlay" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart out2.mp4
```

But png is not a transparent and video hiding behind the picture. How can i set order or "z-index" position of the video to see it OVER the image?

[image]

Comment: Change `[vid][1]` to `[1][vid]`

Comment: @Gyan, in this case - png is not shown : https://c2n.me/4gfPjBc.png

Comment: Likely because your png is smaller than the video. Pad the image, not the video, OR downscale the video.

Comment: @Gyan, png size is 600x554, mp4 is 148x114. I uploaded my files in case you would like to check them... https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gKJCyVU0IgJ8g3zWFhCA-L93lDOWyOS-?usp=sharing

Comment: `-i cat.mp4 -framerate 30 -i dem.png -filter_complex "[1][0]overlay=x=W*.27:y=H*.58" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart out2.mp4`

Comment: @Gyan oh, man! thank you a lot! so magic :)